# Объединить два NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, coredata

Добрый день! В своем проекте использую `Core Data` и необходимо сделать вывод из двух Entity, но не могу понять как объединить результаты первого и второго `NSFetchedResultsController` в один. Выводить нужно в одной таблице без разделения на секции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Варианта тут два.

Первый очевиден: вручную сводить объекты двух `FRC` в один массив. Это, правда, влечёт за собой необходимость реализации довольно муторного механизма, объединяющего отработку вызовов методов протокола `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` обоих контроллеров. Это если хочется сохранить анимацию удаления/добавления/изменения объектов. Если обойтись без – то можно просто пересобирать общий массив и делать `[self.tableView reloadData]` в `-controllerDidChangeContent:`.

Второй вариант более элегантен, и возможен в случае, если удастся основать обе сущности на единой общей абстрактной сущности ([тут](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/KeyConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH30-SW7)). Тогда можно натравить `FRC` на неё, и определять, что именно за объект попался, обычным `-isKindOfClass:`.